# Create action test with a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm trying to test a basic create action.  I have a model `MealPlan` which `has_many :dinners, through: :meals`.  A user can create a MealPlan for the week which will add 7 meals with specific dinners. This works.

I'm having issues testing it though.

```
  setup do
    @user = users(:travis)
    sign_in @user
  end

  test "should create a mealplan" do
    post meal_plans_url, params: { meal_plan: {dinner_ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                                 weekof: Date.today.beginning_of_week.next_week }}

    assert_redirected_to meal_plan_path(MealPlan.last)
  end
end
```

This calls the create method in the meal_plans_controller:

```
    def create
      @meal_plan = current_user.meal_plans.build(meal_plan_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @meal_plan.save!
         format.html { redirect_to @meal_plan, notice: 'Dinner was successfully created.' }
        else
        ...
      end
    end
   end
```

Pretty straight forward I think but whenever I try to save this in tests I get this error:
`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Dinners is invalid` (I added the bang on `save` to see what was going on).

Also, I have fixtures for 7 dinners which I can access when I set these tests up.

This is the meal_plan.rb for some context, again nothing out of the ordinary:

```
class MealPlan < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :meals
    has_many :dinners, through: :meals
end
```

Comment: `dinner_ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. Did you create these dinners?

Comment: They exist in the fixtures- if I go `Dinner.first.id` in the test suite I will get a one, so I’m assuming yes?

Comment: I think there is more to the code that is causing the issue. You are passing ids of dinners in an array but I guess there is some conversion going on and at the end the params are not as they should be. Can you share meal_plan_params action and puts your params before and after this line: `@meal_plan = current_user.meal_plans.build(meal_plan_params)` i.e. what is happening to the params. The issue lies here I guess.

Comment: Params passed in - `{"weekof"=>"2020-01-20", "dinner_ids"=>["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]}` passed params.
Then after that the actual `@meal_plan` produces: `#<MealPlan:0x00007f84253686b0>`

And if I do something like `@meal_plan.dinners` we get: 

`Dinner::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f8b8b22abf0>` so it seems like it's assocating dinners.

Comment: Also `@meal_plan.dinners.each { |d| puts d.name}` will output the name of all the expected dinners from the IDs.

Comment: Please try this: `params: { meal_plan: { dinner_ids: Dinner.where(id: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), weekof: Date.today.beginning_of_week.next_week }}`. I think you missed something in your params conversions, so try this and I think you will figure the issue out.

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you.  You should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
params: { meal_plan: { dinner_ids: Dinner.where(id: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), weekof: Date.today.beginning_of_week.next_week }}
```

I think you missed something in your params conversions, so try this and I think you will figure the issue out.

**Update**

PS. I am so glad we figured it out :-) I hope you also understood what was happening ;-)